# Use wildcard expansion to echo all variables in zsh

Tags: zsh, variable-expansion

With multiple variables beginning with the same pattern can a wildcard be used to echo all matched patterns?

when `zzz1=test1; zzz_A=test2; zzza=test3`

What is the best way to match all variables starting with zzz.  Where something like `echo $zzz*` or `for i in $zzz*; do echo $i; done` would output:

```
test1
test2
test3
```

Comment: I know in `bash` you can use `${!zzz*}` to expand to all variable names that start with `zzz`. There should be something similar in `zsh`, though I don't recall what it is.

Comment: I've posted a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59008514/1126841), though it's possible there is another solution for this.

Comment: It could be done with `typeset -m 'zzz*'` .  Details here though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59009819/4387039

Comment: @Stuber: If you just want to see  variable names starting with a certain stringdisplayed on the command line, you can use _variable completion_: If you type, say, `echo $zzz` and then a TAB character, Zsh shows all variables starting with `zzz`. Ensure that `setopt auto_list` is set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to directly answer based on comments above... No, zsh cannot expand and echo variables using a wildcard, but `typeset` can provide the desired result.

`typeset -m 'zzz*'` outputs:

```
zzz_A=test2
zzz1=test1
zzza=test3
```

or more accurately to get my desired output as explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68035/foo-and-zsh):

```
for i in `typeset +m 'zzz*'`; do echo "${i}:  ${(P)i}"; done
```

```
zzz1:  test1
zzz_A:  test2
zzza:  test3
```

or just...

```
for i in `typeset +m 'zzz*'`; do echo "${(P)i}"; done
```

```
test1
test2
test3
```