# zsh equivalent of bash ${!name*} or ${!name@}

Tags: zsh

In `bash`, there is a parameter expansion to generate the *names* of variables matching a given prefix. For example:

```
$ foo1=a foo2=b four=4
$ echo "${!foo@}"
foo1 foo2
```

Is there an equivalent in `zsh`? I know the `(P)` parameter expansion flag is the equivalent of the similar `bash` indirection expansion `${!foo}`:

```
# bash
$ foo=bar bar=3
$ echo ${!foo}
3

# zsh
% foo=bar bar=3
% echo ${(P)foo}
3
```

but as far as I can tell, `(P)` does not also handle prefix matching.

```
% echo "${(P}foo@}"
zsh: bad substitution
```

There doesn't seem to be any way to perform any type of globbing on a parameter *name*, only on the expansion *of* a parameter.

(This seems to be a necessary precursor for a solution for "[Use wildcard expansion to echo all variables in zsh](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59007726/1126841)", though I could be mistaken about that.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`typeset -m`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-typeset) could rescue:

> `-m`
>
> If the `-m` flag is given the name arguments are taken as patterns (use quoting to prevent these from being interpreted as file patterns). With no attribute flags, all parameters (or functions with the `-f` flag) with matching names are printed (the shell option `TYPESET_SILENT` is not used in this case).
>
> -- [zshbuiltins(1), shell builtin commands, typeset](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-typeset)

```
% foo1=a foo2=b four=4
% typeset -m 'foo*'
foo1=a
foo2=b
% typeset +m 'foo*'
foo1
foo2
% setopt extendedglob
% print -l ${$(typeset +m 'foo*')/(#m)*/${(P)MATCH}}
a
b
```

---

Or [`$parameters`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#index-parameters-1) from `zsh/parameters` module could help:

> `parameters`
>
> The keys in this associative array are the names of the parameters currently defined.
>
> -- [zshmodules(1), the zsh/parameter module, parameters](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#index-parameters-1)

```
% foo1=a foo2=b four=4
% print -l ${(Mk)parameters:#foo*}
foo1
foo2
% setopt extendedglob
% print -l ${${(Mk)parameters:#foo*}/(#m)*/${(P)MATCH}}
a
b
```

Comment: Ah, I thought I remembered `parameters` being defined, though couldn't remember where I saw it. Didn't see it in `man zshparams`, so thought I had imagined it.